# Search range for cell containing a string then return last character from that address

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make formula that will return the last character from a cell that contains a specific word.

For that I need to find the  cell.

I tried

```
=IF(
  COUNTIF(B$3:V$23;
    CONCATENATE(B27; "*"));
  RIGHT(B$3:V$23);
  0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Find Cells that Contain a String

Two case insensitive formulas that search within a range for any cells that include a specific text string:

- **Formula 1:** Returns cell addresses
- **Formula 2:** Returns cell addresses & last character

### Returns Cell Addresses

```
=IFERROR(
  SORT(QUERY(TOCOL(
    BYROW(A1:C100, LAMBDA(r, 
      BYCOL(r, LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(
        ADDRESS(ROW(r)/REGEXMATCH(c, "(?i)"&E2)/(LEN(E2)>0),
          COLUMN(c))))))),1))), "No Matches!")
```

[image]

### Return Cell Addresses & Last Character

```
=IFERROR(SORT(
  QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TOCOL(
    BYROW(A1:C1000, LAMBDA(r, 
      BYCOL(r, LAMBDA(c, IFERROR(
        CELL("address", c) &"➡️"& LOWER(RIGHT(TRIM(c),
         1/(1/REGEXMATCH(c,"(?i)"&E2))/LEN(E2)>0)))))
    )), 1), "➡️")))), "No Matches!")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a cell address based on an `IF` statement.

Use the `CELL` function in your `IF` results. The `ADDRESS` function could also be an option.

- Cell address (Absolute): `=if(B1="abc",cell("address",B1),"no match")`
- Cell Column: `=if(B1="abc",cell("col",B1),"no match")`
- Cell Row: `=if(B1="abc",cell("row",B1),"no match")`
- Address (Relative): `=address(B6,B5,4,true)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: screenshot]